# JMXProxy from JBoss to Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, jboss, jmx

I have multiple Tomcats and one JBoss.

In JBoss i like to proxy about 100 Tomcat's JMX-Beans using "JRMPProxyFactory". I have all the interfaces in jboss but i dont know where i have to add the Tomcat's ip-addresses.

This is my `tomcat99-service.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<server>
   <mbean code="org.jboss.invocation.jrmp.server.JRMPProxyFactory"
      name="jboss.jmx:type=adaptor,name=Remote,protocol=jrmp,service=proxyFactory">
      <depends optional-attribute-name="InvokerName">jboss:service=invoker,type=jrmp</depends>
      <depends optional-attribute-name="TargetName">tomcat99:service=JMX</depends>
      <attribute name="JndiName">Tomcat99Target</attribute>
      <attribute name="InvokeTargetMethod">true</attribute>
      <attribute name="ExportedInterfaces">myinterface</attribute>
   </mbean>
</server>
```

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, JRMPProxyFactory uses normal MBeans found using the normal ObjectName rules.  You don't need to configure any IP addresses, except in your client MBean definitions.  If your tomcats are remote, then you should use [JMXRemote](https://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2005/12/20/introduction-to-jmxremote.html) to delegate to the remote MBeans, and [enable JMXRemote](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/monitoring.html#Enabling_JMX_Remote) in each of your tomcats.

You could use [tomcat's own proxy servlet](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/manager/JMXProxyServlet.html) for a lighter-weight alternative which doesn't require a local client in JBoss.

You're probably not using Mule, but their page [The Pros and Cons of Using Tomcat JMX](http://www.mulesoft.com/tcat/tomcat-jmx) does contain quite a few pointers and, of course, some pros and cons.